# Locate Points that are close to other Points in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, optimization, point

I am working on building a gravity simulator and I want to run the back end of it (dealing with the particles) in Haskell. I have my Point data like this:

```
data Point = Point {
  key :: Int,
  x :: Double,
  y :: Double,
  r :: Double
} deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

Where a `key` is just some unique identifier, the `x` is the x-position, the `y` the y-position, and `r` being the radius of the sphere that surrounds the point.

Say I have a list of points `[Point]`. I would like to grab all the points from this list that are going to be touching. This means that `(distance between Point1 and Point2) <= (radius1 + radius2)`.

Is there a fast way I check this condition for each element against every other element relatively quickly? I feel like choosing one element, looping through the list, and then repeating that action for every element of the list could be rather slow when I have a list that is longer than a certain number of points.

Thanks!

Comment: [There are many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search). I'd recommend to look into triangle inequality.

Comment: You might like to read about how [Chipmunk, an existing 2D physics library](http://chipmunk-physics.net/release/ChipmunkLatest-Docs/#cpSpace-SpatialHash) handles this problem.

Comment: I would recommend a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or some similar tree structure where you first insert all the points into the structure and then extract them based on some criterion of closeness. You can avoid comparing all points with all other points by sorting them in each dimension. (The sorting step can be the same as the step where you insert something into a tree.)

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. Thanks for the replies. I did some stuff with list comprehensions, but I know it's not the fastest way. I will definitely look into your ways and see if I can apply them to my problem.